# Ansible multiple password vaults in group_vars file

Tags: ansible

I am having an issue with Ansible attempting to decode the incorrect vault when passing a command in.

The setup is a follows:

My ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
transport=smart
hostfile=./hosts
host_key_checking=False
timeout=5

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = ""
```

My hostfile:

```
[BigIP-Devices]
BigIP-1
BigIP-2

[Cisco-Devices]
Cisco-1
Cisco-2
TEST1
```

My group_vars:

```
BigIP-Devices   <  This is a vault encrypted with bigip-vaultkey
Cisco-Devices   <  This is a vault encrypted with cisco-vaultkey
bigip-vaultkey
cisco-vaultkey
```

Both the vaults are like the following with different details for each:

```
---
 ansible_ssh_user: user
 ansible_ssh_pass: password
```

I am trying to use the following command:

```
ansible -c ssh Cisco-Devices  --vault-password-file ./group_vars/cisco-vaultkey --limit TEST1  -m raw -a "show version"
```

Even though it's calling Cisco-Devices in the command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! Decryption failed on /home/users/ansible/device-access/group_vars/BigIP-Devices
```

However, if I move the BigIP files out of group_vars, it works correctly.

Any one have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is an expected behaviour.
All host patterns and limits are applied after full inventory is parsed.

In your case Ansible discovers `BigIP-Devices` and `Cisco-Devices` groups and tries to load corresponding group variables.

If you never execute your playbook on `BigIP-Devices` and `Cisco-Devices` at the same time, you probably want to separate them into different inventories like:

```
./inventories/
./inventories/bigip/hosts
./inventories/bigip/group_vars/all/BigIP-Devices
./inventories/
./inventories/cisco/hosts
./inventories/cisco/group_vars/all/Cisco-Devices
```

and add required inventory with `-i inventories/bigip`.

P.S. Or use same vault password for all files.

Comment: That makes sense and I thought it might be the case, but was really hoping it wasn't!

Many thanks for the help.